# Having problem negating statement

Tags: logic

So the question is $\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}, \exists \epsilon >0$ such that  $\forall \delta>0, |x-y|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$

My answer was: $\exists x, y\in \mathbb{R}\textrm{ such that }\forall \epsilon>0$, $\exists \delta<0 \textrm{ such that }|x-y|<\delta \land |f(x)-f(y)|>\epsilon$

However, the solution is: $\exists x,y\in\mathbb{R}\textrm{ such that }\forall\epsilon>0,\exists\delta>0\textrm{ such that }|x-y|<\delta\land|f(x)-f(y)|\geq\epsilon$.

My question is how come $\delta$ is not $<0$ or $\leq 0$ and why $|f(x)-f(y)|\geq\epsilon$

Comment: The "procedure" is: put a negation in front and move it inside.

Comment: To do this, you need the rule for qauntifiers: $\lnot \forall$ is $\exists \lnot$ and $\lnot \exists$ is $\forall \lnot$.

Comment: Usefule suggestion: proceed step by step.

Comment: When you end with the quantifiers, you need propositional "transformation rules"; specifically: the negatio of $p \to q$ is $p \land \lnot q$.

Comment: Reagrding your mistekaes: negation of $\forall \delta > 0 \text { blah}$. This is and abbreviation for $\forall \delta \ (\delta > 0 \to \text { blah})$.

Comment: Thus, its negation will be: $\exists \delta\  \lnot ( \delta > 0 \to \text { blah})$. Using the above propositional transformation, we have: $\exists \delta (\delta >0 \land \lnot \text { blah})$.

Comment: This one, in turn, abbreviates to: $\exists \delta > 0 \lnot \text { blah}$.

Answer (score 0):

Delta should never be less than zero!!

You are correct in negating the earlier symbols $\forall$ and $\exists$ by exchanging them. But once we say there is a delta with $\vert x-y\vert < \delta$ AND $\vert f(x)-f(y)\vert \geq \epsilon$, do you see how that contradicts the usual definition? This is precisely the form a counterexample would take.

Comment: are you saying it is because we need to preserve $|x−y|<δ$ is true and if we make $\delta$ less than zero than $|x−y|<δ$ would not hold true?

Comment: Precisely! That and you will never ever want delta < 0.

Comment: but then why would you negate $\delta$ at all? like why would you change $\forall$ to $\exists$ for $\delta$ if it could possibly make |x−y|<δ not hold true?

Comment: We want to negate the statement that
"there is an epsilon that for every delta so and so holds true".

If we can say that 
"for all possible epsilons, there is a delta for which actually, it's false"
then we have successfully negated the statement.